# Resize presented controller due to content changes when presented with UIModalPresentationFormSheet in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios8

I have a presented controller where:

```
modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

Before presenting I set

```
preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 400);
```

Then the content of presented VC is changed and I need to have it's height changed with animation. Steps:

```
self.view.superview.bounds = newBounds;
```

Now don't work, Apple introduced `UIPresentationController` and I can't figure out how to use it in order to resize the already presented VC.

Comment: are you working in swift.If you are working in swift then uipresentationcontroller will work.otherwise ur code is normal

Comment: dont set this.. this always sets the bounds wrongly.self.view.superview.bounds = newBounds;instead try to set preferedcontentsize in presenting view controller after content changes

Comment: set preferedcontentsize in presenting view controller after content changes does nothing for me, did you try it? did you manage to resize using preferedcontentsize?